# Angular JS Auto-update view from events

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, node-webkit

I have a list that is being fed to the view, it is shown correctly but when an event fires that event could add an item to the list and I want angular to update the view with that new item on the list.

So the idea is:

```
.factory('Files', function() {
  return service.getFiles()
})

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, Files) {
  $scope.files = Files
})
```

Now on the `service`:

```
Service.prototype.getFiles = function() {
  return this.files
}
```

And the events that add the the list:

```
this.on('created', function(f) {
  this.files.push(f)
})
```

So when the event `created` is emitted it adds to the list of files `this.files`, the factory that points to the `service.getFiles()` should be able to see that the data has new stuff.

```
Note: 
  This is all local, the events are done with node.js watching a folder.
  This is using Nodewebkit and AngularJS and Node.JS Modules
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is listen for the events and call `$scope.$apply` to refresh the view by scope.

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, Files) {
   $scope.files = Files.getFiles();
   Files.on("created", function(){
      $scope.files = Files.getFiles();
      $scope.$apply();
   });
})
```

Comment: Yo I just want to ask something about values from a factory not updating when the value is modified. Why is that?

`$scope.selectedSource = Setting.getLastSelectedSource()`

But when I `Setting.setLastSelectedSource data.id`, `$scope.selectedSource` doesn't get detected by.
`.container-fluid(ng-show="sources")`

Comment: What about, how to update the view when the event fires in a different controller ? ( i.e: event fires in the headerCtrl and there's something to update in the footerCtrl ) ?

Comment: Use the angular event engine. Maybe go over the rootScope.on / rootScope.emit